# using data URI with svg for background image

Tags: css, svg, jsx

I'm trying to set the background image of a tag using the background-image property and raw string data but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have:

```
backgroundImage: 'url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" /></svg>")'
```

I am using react and so this is being used inside jsx tags. Interestingly I can do this with an image tag and it works. I've tried various quotation combinations with no success.

Comment: You have a quotes problem. Please test this: `background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Crect width='300' height='100' style='fill:rgb(0,0,255)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");`

Comment: Yes, for IMG src you only have to escape the **#**, in CSS you also need to escape **<** and **>**